# make two inner boxes vertically aligned center in the effective way?

Tags: javascript, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

```css
.dd{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px soild red;
  background:#000;
}
.dd .d1{
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   border:1px solid green;
  display:inline-block;
  
}
.dd .d2{
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   border:1px solid green;
  display:inline-block;
  
}
.dd .d3{
   height:40px;
   width:30px;
   border:1px solid yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd">
   <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
  <div class="d3"></div>
</div>
```

In my project, i always cannot find a good way to vertically elements. Anyone has good points in making elements(any circustances) vertically aligned?

My own stupid way:

when the out div do not have height, then it's easier for me , i often make the margin-top eaquls the margin-bottom, and it's vertically aligned like this:

```css
.dd{
   height:auto;
   width:100%;
   background:#000;
}

.dd>div:first-child{
  display:inline-block;
   margin-top:1em;
   margin-bottom:1em;
    height:80px;
  width:50px;
   border:1px solid red;
  margin-left:1em;
}
.dd>div:last-child{
  display:inline-block;
   margin-top:1em;
   margin-bottom:1em;
   
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
   
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

but in this case, i cannot find a good practice for now, anyone have an idea?

**SECOND ADDED**

And i change my stupid way:

`.dd>div:first-child{height:50px }`

to

`.dd>div:first-child{height:80px }`

seems that my stupid way did work either unless you change height:80px back to height:50px

## About what i am about to achieve is that I want the innerDivs(inline-block) to place in the center(vertically) of the fixed-height outer div(that's, i wanna make the inner divs' margin-top and margin-bottom to be equal)

Please do make more expanationation here so we can understand why it can work,thanks

Comment: You can just use the vertical-align property in CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Which two boxes you want vertical align? what is your expected output?

Comment: just add the similar expected snippet, have a look,thanks

Comment: @TingSun ,about vertical-align,it did not work for me,you can try it on  the .dd .d1 selector ,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
.dd {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This way any items within the .dd container will be vertically centered. If you want everything horizontally centered as well then write:

```
justify-content: center;
```

**EDIT**
Note: this works nonetheless the height of the elements within the flex container.

Comment: yeah,kind of using this before, but i found it is not flexible if i wanna change very little stuff like margin , paddding,and such. Did i not understand it throughly or do we have any other option?

Comment: @franklee Could you try to explain this graphically? Or what exactly is what you need?

Comment: @franklee Which of these are you trying to achieve? Here's [an image with a few examples](http://i.imgur.com/SouWTq1.png).

Comment: I made a working example of this here: [http://codepen.io/danielpox/pen/eJjONy/](http://codepen.io/danielpox/pen/eJjONy/)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html/), in CSS2 you can use the `table-cell` display and the `vertical-align` property, but I'm not a big fan of this kind of code.

This is a fiddle of the code using that:
https://jsfiddle.net/Laf2wv4n/1/

Comment: @angle9215, it seems that the d1 and d2 elements are not vertically aligned center since there is obviously more margin-top than its margin-bottom

Comment: I just got that fixed, please check the fiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/Laf2wv4n/1/

Comment: It can work now,thanks for your effort. Like you, I am not a fan of table way either,too old fashiion.But you also give us a way to get it out.   Hope there is another way to do that perfectly, which can give us more flexible

Comment: I agree with you there, but unfortunately it's tables for compatibility or something new for broken support and problems across the many browsers, maybe some javascript here could provide a better solution

Answer (score 1):

- I have use `:pseudo` element `:before` of the parent i.e `dd` to vertically align the inner elements
- Every inline element can the vertically centre using `vertical-align:middle`

I have used pseudo element so that it can be used as a `inline-block` element with `100%` `height` of the parent

```css
.dd {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px soild red;
  background: #000;
}
/* added to vertiaclly align the elements inside */
.dd:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%; /* set the height of the element to 100% so that the inner elements can align to its full height */
  display: inline-block; /* this is the property which is need to vertically center */
  width: 1px; /* set the width to 1px */
  margin-left: -1px; /* so that the width doesnt effect the children */
  vertical-align: middle; /* is added to vertically align the elements */
}
.dd div {
  vertical-align: middle; /* is added to vertically align the elements */
}
/* end */
.dd .d1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dd .d2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dd .d3 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd">
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
  <div class="d3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool,it's also a way to achieve the vertically centered effects but can you put more details  about why the :pseudo element can do the job so we can learn it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vertical aligning text or blocks is very old and known html/css problem. Through years raised many solutions which depends of browsers functionality and initial conditions (text or block, known or not height of elements etc).

Chris Coyier tried to gather all technique in one complete guide on its own website and categorized them by most often use cases.

[Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

My favorites are most modern methods by now: `flexbox` and aligning through `transform: translateY(-50%)` rule. They are the most concise and bright.